# Can 'almost already' be used in a valid sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, american-english

Is the following a valid sentence?

> "I'm *almost already* done"

The only thing I can think of is that 'almost' can refer to the time while 'already' can refer to the amount of work remaining.

Comment: "Already done" means it was done in the past, so I don't understand how one could be *almost* already done. "Almost done" would be fine. "Already almost done" would also be fine.

Comment: I could certainly see it being used facetiously, especially as a response to any variation of ''I want it done yesterday''.

Comment: There's *almost done* and *already done*. Syntactically, *almost already done* is fine. But it's unidiomatic and almost certainly redundant. Unless it's used in a very specific context. *"You mean you're already done?" "No, but almost … I'm **almost** already done."*

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica post that as the answer so that I can close it.